# How to disable ApplicationInsights for Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: visual-studio, azure-application-insights, visual-studio-2022

When I start Visual Studio 2022, the application hangs.  When I start in safemode, no issues.

It appears that devenv.exe is stuck in a loop while querying *.tm files for ApplicationInsights.
[image]

I am only starting the application, so there's no project or solution at this point. How can I disable ApplicationInsights and allow Visual Studio 2022 to finish opening?

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2022
Version 17.1.4
VisualStudio.17.Release/17.1.4+32407.343
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.8.04084
```

Answer (score -1):

To remove Application Insights, you'll need to remove the NuGet packages and references from the API in your application. You can uninstall NuGet packages by using the Package Management Console or Manage NuGet Solution in Visual Studio.

Suggest you to refer this official document on: [How to remove Application Insights in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/remove-application-insights?tabs=net) which will show two ways to remove NuGet Packages and what was automatically added in your project.

Comment: There is no application project or solution file loaded.  My question is for the devenv.exe by itself.